# react native community Viewpager is not revealing part of next slide/view

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-ios

Current behaviour: only one slide/view is visible in one screen.

I want something like this
[image]

How this can be achieved?
I am using this package.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/viewpager

Here is example.

```
const MyPager = () => {
  return (
    
    <ViewPager style={styles.viewPager} initialPage={0} pageMargin={0} collapsable={false}>
      <View key="1" style={styles.pageS}>
        <Text>First page</Text>
      </View>
      <View key="2" style={styles.pageS}>
        <Text>Second page</Text>
      </View>
      <View key="3" style={styles.pageS}>
        <Text>Third page</Text>
      </View>
    </ViewPager>
    
  );
};



const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  viewPager: {
    backgroundColor: "grey",
    marginTop:100,
    height:400,
  },
  pageS:{
    marginHorizontal:10,
    borderWidth:1,
  },
});
```

Comment: Provide us a piece of your code, please.

Comment: @J.Doe just created a new app and noticed it's same for both android and iOS.
have edited question and put code.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can give a marginHorizontal to your page View and add pageMargin attribute for the PagerView.

```
<PagerView
    initialPage={0}
    pageMargin={-46}
    style={styles.viewPager}
    offscreenPageLimit={2}
    onPageScroll={handlePageScroll}>
    <View style={{marginHorizontal: 32}} />
</PagerView>
```

Comment: Why is `pageMargin` -46?